# React.memo custom comparison not avoiding excessive re-renders in stock trading app

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, rerender, react-memo

I am working on a performance-critical section of a stock trading React application that involves a large number of components displaying real-time data.
I'm using `React.memo()` with a custom compare function to optimize rendering and avoid unnecessary re-renders. However, I am noticing that the components are still re-rendering more often than expected.

Here's a simplified version of my `ExpensiveComponent`:

```js
import React from "react";

const ExpensiveComponent = ({ data, onAction }) => {
  // Expensive render logic here
  console.log("ExpensiveComponent rendered");

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render data */}
      <button onClick={() => onAction(data.id)}>Perform action</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  // Assume data objects have the same reference if they are equal
  return prevProps.data === nextProps.data && prevProps.onAction === nextProps.onAction;
};

export default React.memo(ExpensiveComponent, areEqual);
```

And here's the parent component that renders multiple instances of `ExpensiveComponent`:

```js
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ExpensiveComponent from "./ExpensiveComponent";
import dataService from "./dataService";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState(dataService.getData());

  const handleAction = useCallback((id) => {
    console.log("Action performed on item with id:", id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {dataList.map((data) => (
        <ExpensiveComponent key={data.id} data={data} onAction={handleAction} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

I expect `ExpensiveComponent` instances to only re-render when the `data` or `onAction` props change. However, when I check the console, I can see that the "ExpensiveComponent rendered" message appears more frequently than expected, indicating unnecessary re-renders.

Am I missing something in my implementation of `React.memo` or the custom compare function that might cause these unnecessary re-renders? Any insights from React experts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The minimal example you provided works fine. I believe there's something missing in the puzzle here.